# Xamarin Profiler not starting on Xamarin.Forms Targeting Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, xamarin-profiler

I have a Xamarin.Forms app, that only targets an Android build.

I installed Xamarin Profiler from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/tools/profiler/?tabs=windows#download-and-install

After installation, I can see the Xamarin Profiler option in VS:

[image]

From VS 2022 Enterprise (Version 17.7.3), when I run Xamarin Profiler (Version 1.6.10.15), the application does not start. The Profiler usually gives the error *Application [my_app].MainActivity stopped*:

[image: Tell me something I don't know]

Occasionally, I get the error Sorry, something went wrong trying to run [my_app_name]: Runtime installed on the device Samsung [device_name] is too old. Deploy your app again with a newer version of Xamarin studio.

[image]

The Xamarin.Forms project uses .net standard 2.0, and targets Android 13.

It works fine when debugging in VS though, hitting breakpoints etc.

How do I run Xamarin Profiler in Visual Studio? Alternatively, where could one safely download "Xamarin Studio" for Windows 11? I can't find any official Microsoft links for downloading Xamarin Studio, as an alternative, with the intent to use Xamarin Profiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the exact same issue.

If you installed Xamarin profiler via Microsoft's website, try uninstalling it and install it via the Visual Studio Installer.

[image: Screenshot here]

Answer (score -1):

> I can't find any official Microsoft links for downloading Xamarin Studio, as an alternative, with the intent to use Xamarin Profiler.

Xamarin Studio has been discontinued and is no longer available for download. Instead, you can use Visual Studio to develop Xamarin apps. Open **Visual Studio Installer** select the **.NET Multi-platform App UI development** workload and check **Xamarin** under *Optional*:

[image]

For more info you can refer to the official doc: [Installing Xamarin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/get-started/installation/?pivots=windows-vs2022).

Comment: I have already done that. The question is not how to install Xamarin Studio, but rather how to fix my issue wirh Xamarin Profiler.

Comment: If you create a new project, and then run Xamarin Profiler to see if it can start?

Comment: Same exact result, with a new Xamarin.Forms app